# How to force Pillow to resize an image to an arbitrary size?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need to resize images, from all different sizes to 144x144.

All sizes: from 968x565, from 25x48, from 400x400, etc. Don't know the input. I'm using Pillow library from Python. I don't mind losing aspect ratio.

Problem is: when using `resize` method, some images get complete random sizes. Not always, but just some of them don't respect the arbitrary size of 144x144 I gave to the method. [Here is a sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7v66.jpg).

I tried resizing these images using Mac OS X Yosemite's Preview and it works flawlessly. What do I need to do in Pillow to force 144x144 size and work at least like Preview in mac?

I can't post the whole code, but the snippet that resizes is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('canvas_wheat.jpg')
im.resize((144, 144), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save('144.jpg', optimize=True, quality=20)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific example that doesn't work? Because it works for me.

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you have imagemagick? I've created a sample that has this problem: `convert -size 952x804 xc:wheat  canvas_wheat.jpg`. If you don't have it you can download the sample from http://imgur.com/DdxullE

Comment: @MarkRansom I added a small snippet as well.

Comment: I don't have Imagemagick, sorry. I did download your sample and it resizes to 144x144 just fine for me. I'm using the original PIL and not Pillow though. What size output do you get?

Comment: @MarkRansom the same, as if it didn't resize at all.

Comment: You know it creates a new image, right? It doesn't modify the existing image.

Comment: Yep. Both canvas_wheat.jpg and 144.jpg have the same size.

Comment: @MarkRansom you were absolutely right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are getting there is that the `resize` method returns a
*new* image object, you are not storing anywhere. The original image `im` is the same that has been loaded.

Check the examples on this interactive session:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> img = Image.open("image.jpg")
>>> img.size
(952, 804)
>>> img2 = img.resize((144,144), Image.ANTIALIAS)
>>> img.size
(952, 804)
>>> img2.size
(144, 144)
>>>
```

Comment: @MarkRansom was right. "You know it creates a new image, right? It doesn't modify the existing image.". I need to sleep.

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS it's an easy mistake to make. The PIL interface isn't consistent, sometimes it modifies in-place and sometimes it returns a new object. And Python itself doesn't give you any hints. The method name is the final misdirection, it's an action verb that just naturally makes you think it's modifying the image.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I agree PIL is inconsistent in this regard. The way to go is either to have the docs open, or try the methods in an interactive prompt as you go.